Issue with column cluster chart with Power BI
I'm trying to create a clustered column chart, which visualises the amount of arrears by tenancy tenure. I created a column which categorises these tenures (tenancy tenure band) and then a further one to put them in the order I want it to display the data (tenancy tenure band order).
What I was expecting was the visual to display the chart in the following screenshot, except instead of the TenancyTenureBandOrder, it would just show the TenancyTenureBand:

This is what is in the axes:

Now when I try to play around with the drill modes/hierarchy/levels of data, the following happens:

As you can see, it's not in the order that it should be. Ideally, the chart should reflect the table visual below:

The really weird thing is, I applied the same method to another visual except instead of tenancy tenure, I visualised the age, and it worked perfectly fine:


try to click the three dot on the upper right corner and select the correct sort.

